# Split one button into two separate buttons after a click event in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am just curious if it is possible to replace a button into two buttons which the two buttons occupy the place of the original single buttons after a click event? Also after the click event of one of the two buttons, is it possible to revert to the original view where there is only one button?

So it looks like the *fission* of one button into two buttons and then the *fusion* of two buttons into one button again.

Comment: Hi @Susannn, your question is a bit broad and does not contain any code for what you have already tried doing. I would recommend doing some research on this yourself and giving it shot. If you are unable to figure it out, come back and talk about what you have tried and show the code you used. As of now, I don't think you will get any answers to your question.

Answer (score 1):

welcome to StackOverflow. Yes, it is quite possible, and in the simplest form, not even that difficult. It goes something like this:

1. Make a UI with 3 buttons.
2. Hide two of the, leave the last one visible.
3. On click of the visible button, make the other two buttons visible and hide the clicked button.
4. On click of one of the two buttons, revert the above procedure.

Of course, if you want to add stuff like animations and so, it will be a lot more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

*in .xaml*

```
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button x:Name="btn_big" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Click="Click_big"/>
            <Button x:Name="btn_small1" Grid.Column="1" Visibility="Hidden" Click="Click_small"/>
            <Button x:Name="btn_small2" Grid.Column="2" Visibility="Hidden" Click="Click_small"/>
        </Grid>
```

*in .cs*

```
    private void Click_big(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
      btn_big.Visibility=Visibility.Hidden;
      btn_small1.Visibility=Visibility.Visible;
      btn_small2.Visibility=Visibility.Visible;          
    }

    private void Click_small(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
      btn_big.Visibility=Visibility.Visible;
      btn_small1.Visibility=Visibility.Hidden;
      btn_small2.Visibility=Visibility.Hidden;          
    }
```